# PHP Search only displaying one result?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Could somebody help me, I have a PHP search script (shown below, has HTML around it) that I want to return multiple search results when necessary, but at the moment it doesn't, and I've struggled enough getting it to this point so I'm lost..

```
<?php
                    if(isset($_POST['completedsearch']))
                    {
                            $term = $_POST['query'];
                            $mysql = mysql_connect("localhost","user","password");
                            mysql_select_db("hcsd");
                            $qu = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Sheet1 WHERE COMPANY LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($term)."%' OR LOCATION LIKE '%"$.mysql_real_escape_string($term)."%' OR KEYWORDS LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($term)."%' OR PRODUCTSSERVICES LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($term)."%' "); //selects the row that contains ANYTHING like the submitted string
                            echo "
                                            <table><tr><th>Name</th>
                                            <th>Location</th>
                                            <th>Products/Services</th></tr>
                                            ";
                            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qu))
                                       {

                                            echo "<tr><td>";  
                                            echo $row['COMPANY'];
                                            echo "</td>";
                                            echo "<td>";
                                            echo $row['LOCATION'];
                                            echo "</td>";
                                            echo "<td>";
                                            echo $row['PRODUCTSSERVICES'];
                                            echo "</td></tr></table>";
                            }
                    }
            ?>
```

Search can be seen at www.healthcareservicesdirect.com by searching TV, which should display Sky & Virgin, but as of now, only displays Sky

Comment: Are you sure more than one row is returned from your query?

Comment: you should use MySQLi or PDO instead of mysql_ functions, theyve been deprecated. You should move your table closing tag outside of your while loop.

Comment: No, that's what I need help with, I want it to return multiple rows but it's not. Sorry if I've misunderstood, I have barely any PHP experience..

Comment: Be sure to escape your values for HTML output.  `echo htmlspecialchars($row['COMPANY'])`

Comment: You need to verify that the query as executed actually does return more than one row.  Store it in a string instead of passing it to `mysql_query()`, echo it to the screen, and copy it into a MySQL client.

Comment: @Fredd Thanks, I've been told that and I will at some point, but my boss is on my case to have something up today so for now I can't afford to be completely rewriting it.. Where would I place the </table> tag outside of the while loop?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Sorry, how would I "Store it in a string instead of passing it to mysql_query(), echo it to the screen, and copy it into a MySQL client."?

Comment: @user2965329 `$sql = "SELECT * FROM Sheet1...."; echo $sql;` That's just for debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just looked at it and I saw it lists Virgin!
It is just not in the table as the first entry is. It is at the bottom of the page.
To fix this, you have to leave the echo "" out of the while-loop, because with it you close the table after the first entry, so your code should look like this:

```
<?php
                if(isset($_POST['completedsearch']))
                {
                        $term = $_POST['query'];
                        $mysql = mysql_connect("localhost","user","password");
                        mysql_select_db("hcsd");
                        $qu = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Sheet1 WHERE COMPANY LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($term)."%' OR LOCATION LIKE '%"$.mysql_real_escape_string($term)."%' OR KEYWORDS LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($term)."%' OR PRODUCTSSERVICES LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($term)."%' "); //selects the row that contains ANYTHING like the submitted string
                        echo "
                                        <table><tr><th>Name</th>
                                        <th>Location</th>
                                        <th>Products/Services</th></tr>
                                        ";
                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qu))
                                   {

                                        echo "<tr><td>";  
                                        echo $row['COMPANY'];
                                        echo "</td>";
                                        echo "<td>";
                                        echo $row['LOCATION'];
                                        echo "</td>";
                                        echo "<td>";
                                        echo $row['PRODUCTSSERVICES'];
                                        echo "</td></tr>";
                        }
                        echo "</table>";
                }
        ?>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, can't believe I didn't scroll down to check the rest of the page, I thought it may be something to do with the way I was echo'ing the </table>

Comment: @user2965329 you're welcome. If my answer solved your Problem, I would be glad if you would accept it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try

```
"SELECT * FROM Sheet1 WHERE COMPANY LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($term)."%' OR LOCATION LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($term)."%' OR KEYWORDS LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($term)."%' OR PRODUCTSSERVICES LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($term)."%'"
```

i noticed `LOCATION LIKE '%"$.mysql_real_escape_string($term)."%'` where you had a $

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "
<table><tr><th>Name</th>
<th>Location</th>
<th>Products/Services</th></tr>
";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qu))
{
    echo "<tr><td>";  
    echo $row['COMPANY'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $row['LOCATION'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $row['PRODUCTSSERVICES'];
    echo "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

in response to your comment, try this